# no more geom_label( ) in ggplot2 1.01?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was following [this ggplot2 docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/geom_text.html) try to reproduce text labels with `geom_label`. But I got an error message,

> "could not find function geom_label"

. `?geom_label` also says no such function. I checked on another two computers and got the same error message. All are with *R 3.22*, in *RStudio 0.99.489* or in pure R command. `ggplot2` is version 1.01 installed with `install.packages(ggplot2)`.I did not find a clue from Google. So it seems that `geom_label` has been removed from the latest ggplot2 before any documentation can be made.

My question is: what is used to replace `geom_label`, which produces nice text labels in a boxed background?

Here is the code from the *ggplot2* docs that suppose to produce the figure below.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)))
p + geom_label()
```

[image]

Comment: what's your ggplot2 version?

Comment: 1.01 installed from CRAN

Comment: I am not sure but if you look at http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/geom_text.html (version 1.0.1.9003), I think you have to download the dev version of ggplot2 https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`geom_label` was [implemented on 2015-07-24](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/commits/master/R/geom-label.R). The current version on CRAN (1.0.1) was published on 2015-03-17. You'll need to install the [development version from GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2) if you want to use `geom_label` or wait until it is uploaded to CRAN (which might take a while).

Comment: Thanks. It works. It is not  removed but is too new to be updated to CRAN. I need a ggplot2 history lesson.

Comment: @GL_Li Most developers are hesitant to remove functions. It's far more common that new functions are added. Hadley has a history of renaming his functions, but not of removing functionality.